# Why Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't recognize my graphic card?

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, graphics

In Settings, Ubuntu says my graphic card is unknown :

[image: screenshot]

The command `lspci | grep VGA` gives me this :

[image: screenshot]

**Why ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *System Information* panel in the system settings is not getting the value from the hardware, as `lspci` does, but is getting information from the userspace drivers for Xorg and OpenGL. As a result, depending on which drivers are being used, the requisite information it uses may not be available. In this case, it defaults to displaying `Unknown` rather than the name or type of your graphics card.

More accurately, the panel tells you what graphics system you are using, and not what graphics card you have.

Answer (score -1):

`lspci` gives you a list of devices and their descriptions as reported by the device itself.

The Settings dialogue involvesthe systems  own checking of the signatures of the graphics cards recognised in its own database, quite independent of this description.  This database may be incomplete, and may not include variant cards, but really is not that important.

```
You may find that once you install proprietary drivers, that suddenly the card is recognised. The install may need some changes to your[ \[boot parameters\]][1]...critical appears to be ensure [nomodeset][2] parameter is used
```